# How to avoid restarting rotation of an image?

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, restart, resume

I used an image to rotate using rotate handle. While trying to start rotating
image in greater than `0 degree`(for example `20 degree`), it gets restart from
`0 degree`.

How to resume the rotation without restarting using Jquery and CSS.?

```
var RAD2DEG = 180 / Math.PI;  

var dial = $("#image_box");

$('#left').text(dial.offset().left);
$('#top').text(dial.offset().top);
dial.centerX = dial.offset().left + dial.width()/2;
dial.centerY =  dial.offset().top + dial.height()/2;
$('#centerX').text(dial.centerX);
$('#centerY').text(dial.centerY);

var offset, rotate = false;

dial.find("#rotate_handle").mousedown(function(e) {
  rotate = true;
  offset = Math.atan2(dial.centerY - e.pageY, e.pageX - dial.centerX);
  $('#pageX').text(e.pageX);
  $('#pageY').text(e.pageY);
  $('#offset').text(offset);
});

$(document).mouseup(function() { 
  rotate = false;
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if(rotate) { 
    var newOffset = Math.atan2(dial.centerY - e.pageY, e.pageX - dial.centerX);
    $('#newOffset').text(newOffset);
    var r = (offset - newOffset) * RAD2DEG;
    $('#RAD2DEG').text(RAD2DEG);
    $('#r').text(r);
    dial.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + r + 'deg)');
    dial.css('transform', 'rotate(' + r + 'deg)');
    $('#box').css('-webkit-transform','rotate(' + r + 'deg)');
    $('#box').css('transform','rotate(' + r + 'deg)');
  }
});
```

Code link in [JSfiddle..](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/npmtfLt6/20/)

Answer (score 0):

What if you keep the previous value in a variable and rotate the sum each time?

```
var previousR=0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if (rotate) {
    var newOffset = Math.atan2(dial.centerY - e.pageY, e.pageX - dial.centerX);
    $('#newOffset').text(newOffset);
    var r = (offset - newOffset) * RAD2DEG;
    $('#RAD2DEG').text(RAD2DEG);
    $('#r').text(r);
    r+=previousR;
    dial.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + r + 'deg)');
    dial.css('transform', 'rotate(' + r + 'deg)');
    $('#box').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + r + 'deg)');
    $('#box').css('transform', 'rotate(' + r + 'deg)');
    previousR=r;
  }
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/qNjokL

Comment: In your demo, the image not gets rotate as per the mouse pointer drag. Image rotates very quick...